# Python3.6 parallel repeat timer or multiple timer

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, python-3.6

My code is here.

```
import threading

def checkMinute(num):
    print('check ' + str(num))
    # other python code....
    threading.Timer(10, checkMinute(num)).start() # repeat until ctrl + c

def TimerStart(num):
    threading.Timer(10,checkMinute(num)).start()

if __name__=="__main__":

    t1=threading.Thread(target=TimerStart,args=(10, 1)) # interval is 10 seconds
    t2=threading.Thread(target=TimerStart,args=(10, 2))
    t3=threading.Thread(target=TimerStart,args=(10, 3))
    t1.daemon=True # For stop when ctrl+c
    t2.daemon=True
    t3.daemon=True
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    time.sleep(1000)
```

When start it first, waiting 10 second is worked, so after 10 seconds later timer is start.

But second start in checkMinute, it not wait and only num=1 are activated, 2 and 3 are not.

Console log is like this.

```
check 1 # 00:00:00 -> it not wait 10 second. and only 1 is active.
check 1 # 00:00:00
check 1 # 00:00:00
check 1 # 00:00:00
check 1 # 00:00:00
...
```

And finally error occur.

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00003a2c (most recent call first):
```

How do I make sure to keep the wait time when running the second time in checkMinute?

May console log like this.

```
check 1 # 00:00:00 
check 2 # 00:00:00
check 3 # 00:00:00
check 2 # 00:00:10
check 1 # 00:00:10
check 3 # 00:00:10
check 1 # 00:00:20
check 3 # 00:00:20
check 2 # 00:00:20
check 3 # 00:00:30
...
```

Or Is there other way to use a thread and a timer to periodically iterate in parallel?

Or How to use multiple timer?

Comment: `TimerStart` takes one argument yet you are passing it two? Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you code:

```py
threading.Timer(10,checkMinute(num)).start()
```

You are specifying as the function to be invoked after 10 seconds the *return value* from first calling `checkMinute(num)`, which is `None`. This should be closer to:

```py
threading.Timer(10, checkMinute, args=(num,)).start()
```

But you want to first make the above a daemon thread. And there is no need for `TimerStart`. So try the following:

```py
import threading
import time

def checkMinute(num):
    print('check', num)
    # other python code....
    startTimer(num)

def startTimer(num):
    t = threading.Timer(10, checkMinute, args=(num,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    startTimer(1)
    startTimer(2)
    startTimer(3)
    time.sleep(1000)
    # or instead of sleeping:
    #input('Hit enter to quit...\n')
```